# Array for multiple columns and paste into different sheet, getting #ref at the last row?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I want to copy put a range of columns into an array and paste columns based into a different worksheet using an array.

I want to put column A2 to H from RESOURCEPLANNING into an array and paste column A,B,D,F & G into Resource_Output worksheet, however I get #REF! error at the bottom of my table.

Currently my code is:

```
Sub Resourceplanning_array()
    Dim Var As Variant
    Dim my_Arange As Variant
    Dim rp As Worksheet, rp_opt As Worksheet
    
    Set rp = Sheets("RESOURCE_PLANNING")
    Set rp_opt = Sheets("RP_Output")
    
    Dim cell As Range


my_Arange = rp.Range("A2", rp.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
   Var = Application.Index(my_Arange, Evaluate("row(1:" & [a1].CurrentRegion.Rows.Count & ")"), Array(1, 2, 4, 6, 8))

rp_opt.Range("A1:E" & UBound(Var)) = Var 'Output the Array.
End Sub
```

Comment: The problems seems to be in the `Evaluate("row(1:" & [a1].CurrentRegion.Rows.Count & ")")` part

Comment: There are more rows in `[a1].CurrentRegion.Rows.Count` than in `my_Arange` which starts at `A2`. Use `Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(my_Arange) & ")"`

Answer (score 0):

### Slice a 2D Array

- It is assumed that the data starts in `A1` and has a row of headers.
- You have to use `7` instead of `8` to copy column `G` instead of column `H`.
- `[A1].CurrentRegion.Rows.Count` may yield different results depending on which worksheet is active, so you should rather qualify the range: `rp.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count`.
- `rp.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count` may be different than `rp.Range("H" & rp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`, so you should opt for one (I've opted for the former).
- A quick fix could be `[a1].CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1`, but is not recommended due to the previous two reasons. `rp.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1` would be better.
- Both solutions do the same except for the out-commented 'exclude-headers-parts' in the first solution, which you could use to not include the headers, and the 'clear-contents-part' in the second solution, which you could use to clear the contents below the destination range.
- Adjust the values in the constants section, the workbook reference, and if headers should be excluded (and if the contents below the destination range should be cleared).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub sliceArray()
    
    Const sName As String = "RESOURCE_PLANNING"
    Const sCols As String = "A:H"
    
    Const dName As String = "RP_Output"
    Const dFirst As String = "A1"
    Dim dCols As Variant: dCols = VBA.Array(1, 2, 4, 6, 8) ' 'VBA': zero-based
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    'Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' workbook you're looking at
    
    ' Source Worksheet
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    
    ' Source/Destination Rows Count
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    ' No headers
    'Dim rCount As Long: rCount = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1
    
    ' Source Array
    Dim sData As Variant
    sData = sws.Columns(sCols).Resize(rCount).Value
    ' No headers
    'sData = sws.Columns(sCols).Resize(rCount).Offset(1).Value
    
    ' Destination Array
    Dim dData As Variant
    dData = Application.Index(sData, Evaluate("Row(1:" & rCount & ")"), dCols)
    
    ' Destination Columns Count
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = UBound(dCols) + 1 ' = UBound(dData, 2)
    ' Destination Worksheet
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    ' Destination Range
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(dFirst).Resize(rCount, dcCount)
    
    ' Write
    drg.Value = dData

End Sub

Sub sliceArrayShort()
    
    Const sName As String = "RESOURCE_PLANNING"
    Const sCols As String = "A:H"
    
    Const dName As String = "RP_Output"
    Const dFirst As String = "A1"
    Dim dCols As Variant: dCols = VBA.Array(1, 2, 4, 6, 8)
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Read
    Dim rCount As Long
    Dim sData As Variant
    With wb.Worksheets(sName)
        rCount = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        sData = .Columns(sCols).Resize(rCount).Value
    End With
    
    ' Slice
    Dim dData As Variant
    dData = Application.Index(sData, Evaluate("Row(1:" & rCount & ")"), dCols)
    
    ' Write (& Clear)
    With wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirst).Resize(, UBound(dCols) + 1)
        .Resize(rCount).Value = dData
        '.Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - rCount + 1) _
            .Offset(rCount).ClearContents
    End With

End Sub
```